# What is the point of Kernel#select in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux

I'm working on a ruby script that ultimately starts up a system process that takes quite a while. I need to read from the stderr of this process and react to it depending on what is output.

I'm currently doing it as such:

```
Open3.popen3(cmd_to_run) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, waitthread|
  stderr.each_line do |line|
    # look out for specific lines and react to them accordingly
  end
end
```

But I've also seen implementations to achieve something similar but doing it with [kernel#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-select):

```
Open3.popen3(cmd_to_run) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, waitthread|
  io = select([stderr], nil, nil, 30)

  if io.nil?
    log("Command timed out during Kernel#select")
    return
  end

  io[0][0].each_line do |line|
    # look out for specific lines and react to them accordingly
  end

end
```

I've read the pickaxe description of what select does, but I'm confused as to why I should (of if I should) use it? The first method works just the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably two reasons:

1. You can use timeout, which you can't with `each_line`
2. You can wait for more than one `IO` object, e. g. `io = select([stdout, stderr])` and more than one event (e.g. write event or exception too)

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to why I need to "wait" on the IO object? Why aren't they available immediately after starting the process?

Comment: IO objects are available immediately, but when you try to read `stdout` for example and there is nothing there (yet), your monitoring process will block. Imagine your system process printed some diagnostic to `stderr` and is waiting for your reply, but it was `stderr`, not `stdout`, so you will be waiting for something on `stdout` forever. `select` returns you first available IO object from the list where something happened so you can process it and `read` will not block as there is something.